# Iterate over lines that start with a number

Tags: python

I have a file that has many lines, the first four lines start with some letters (a word) and the rest start with a number. I want to iterate over the lines that start with a number (three-digit number, eg '123' followed by different variables containing both letters and numbers) and ignore the first 4 lines. This is what I have done, but it gives me a blank list in an output.

```
number = []  
for line in infile.readline():  
    line = line.rstrip()  
    if line.startswith('[0-9]'):
        number.append(line.split()[0])  
print number
```

Why is the 'number' list empty in my output?

This is what the infile looks like:

```
Value = 152  
Numb = 0.005  
Pos = 75  
Samp = 12.5  
150    K    0.345  
234    T    0.764  
565    X    0.345
```

Comment: Always post real code in questions. What you have here has syntax errors.

Comment: Is the indentation correct? This won't run.

Comment: I fixed it, I think. @edg is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`startswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) takes a string, not a regular expression. You want [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match).

EDIT: or `import string; line.startswith(tuple(string.digits))` (thanks @GarethRees)

Comment: A string or a tuple! (So `line.startswith(tuple('0123456789'))` would work.)

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but the easiest way to skip lines is:

```
from itertools import islice
with open('file') as fin:
    for line in islice(fin, 4, None):
        pass # do something
```

Comment: I usually do `for _ in range(4): f.readline()` but that's not general